# Mantaining an array and some nested form fields consistent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm using cocoon to handle some form fields but I need to use the values of the active form fields elsewhere on the page, specifically on an array that is used elsewhere; so I need to populate the form fields with the array and when one changes, change the other.

What I'm currently doing is, whenever the array is modified, I remove all form fields, add them again but then I can't access them by the index and when one is changed I'm unsure how to catch the change and get the actual index modified, given how cocoon handles inserting and deleting, the index isn't consistent with what's shown.

Adding code for reference:

I have this function to clear out forms, make new ones, but can't populate from the field_coords array as I'm unsure as to how to actually access the form_fields.

```
function redo_forms(){
  $('.remove_point').each(function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
  });
  for(i=0; i < field_coords.length; i++){
    $('.add_point').trigger('click');
    //add data here
  };
}
```

And the forms themselves are defined as:

```
<tbody>
    <%= f.fields_for :points do |point| %>
        <%= render 'admin/shared/point_fields', {:f => point} %>
    <% end %>
    <tr id='new_point'>
        <td colspan="3">
            <%= link_to_add_association t(:add_points), f, :points, {'data-association-insertion-method' => 'before', 'data-association-insertion-node' => '#new_point', :partial => 'admin/shared/point_fields', :class => 'add_point'} %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and:

```
<tr class='nested-fields'>
  <td><%= f.text_field :lat, :class => 'coordinate_lat span8' %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :lng, :class => 'coordinate_long span8' %></td>
  <td><%= link_to_remove_association t(:remove_point), f, :class => 'remove_point' %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you please add your code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the dirty function in place of .click?

I feel like click would send a blank record, being it would *click*, your event fires sending nothing, then the user types value.

Also, is there a reason you prefer not to setup the controller to hold the information you're clearing out & re-entering?

Comment: I used .click because I figured part of the way to create a field and then give it a value would be something akin to .click followed by accessing the created form and setting its value, but I couldn't find the way to access it.

As for why I didn't setup the controller to hold the array; while I do initially copy the original set of points from the controller to the javascript client-side code, I hadn't realized I could set up an ajax request to update the data; I guess that could work, but it seems a bit excessive, maybe.

Comment: I'm not super versed on it or I'd walk you through it - but I followed some blogs - [Dirty Explaination](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/dirty-forms/) & have a jquery gem saved from last week which I haven't installed - [gem](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms).